# Where does IntelliJ IDEA store database console scripts?

Tags: intellij-idea

I couldn't find answer to this questions on SO despite long search. For some reason I thought I've seen it before.

Do you guys know in which file IDEA saves content of database console scripts ?

I thought it was in `dataSources.ids` but I don't see scripts there, only connection settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try looking into the IntelliJ cache folder.

For me I did not find the database scripts themselves, but found a *history* of all the sql statements executed here :

```
`c:\Users\$user\.IntelliJIdea13\system\userHistory\*.xml`
```

(Am on IntelliJ Idea EAP).

Comment: Oooo, 13 - nice! Did you install it last friday (the 13th) ? And thanks for the answer, good to know.

Comment: @vikingsteve :D, Friday the 13th would have caused it to not startup, right? (That actually [did happen](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113512) just a day before, no kidding)

Comment: Well it's monday 16th so your issue should be resolved now... :)

Comment: :). I have had it installed for a bit now (since build 132.27 which came out on Aug 29th). Decided to take the plunge after reading the release notes of the past builds (See ['*Release Notes*'](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP) ). Have been using it as my main IDE for three weeks. Have been happy thus far.

Comment: If someone is using IntelliJ or Datagrip on macos - `~/Library/Preferences/DataGrip2019.1/consoles/db/`

Comment: in IJ 2019 it's `Users\$user\.IntelliJIdea2019.2\config\consoles\.history\*.xml`

Answer (score 4):

On newer version of IntelliJ (2020+) for Mac it can be found here:

`~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdeaYOUR_VERSION/consoles/db`

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Mac OS X, and as of IntelliJ IDEA 14, this gets stored here:

```
~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea14/userHistory/*.xml
```

I suspect that OS X updates sometimes clear `~/Library/Caches`, because after the OS X 10.10.2 update I lost my database console history.  If the contents of your database console are important to you, make sure you are backing up this folder and not excluding it in your Time Machine backup!

*Update (2016/09/23)*: At some point they moved it out of Caches and into the preferences folder, which is good because you no longer have to worry about macOS updates wiping it out.  For example, it is here in the current version:

```
~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2016.2/consoles/db/
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac versions store it at :

```
~/Library/Preferences/IDEA version/consoles/db/
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding Ubuntu default to the list of answers, ofc you change IntelliJIdea2020.1 with your version.

```
~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/consoles
```